# Determining whether each row exists in another MySQL table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables that are very similar. For example, let's say that each row has two ID numbers, and a data value. The first ID number may occur once, twice, or not be included, and the second ID number is either 1 or -1. The data value is not important, but for the sake of this example, we'll say it's an integer. For each pair of ID numbers, there can only be one data value, so if I have a data point where the ID's are 10 and 1, there won't be another 10 and 1 row with a different data value. Similarly, in the other table, the data point with ID's 10 and 1 will be the same as in the first table. I want to be able to select the rows that exist in both tables for the sake of changing the data value in all of the rows that are in both. My command for MySQL so far is as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM schema.table1
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * from schema.table1 
    WHERE schema.table1.ID1 = schema.table2.ID1
    and schema.table1.ID2 = schema.table2.ID2);
```

I want to be able to have this code select all the rows in table1 that are also in table2, but allow me to edit table1 values.

I understand that by creating a union of the two tables, I can see the rows that exist in both tables, but would this allow me to make changes to the actual data values if I changed the values in the merged set? For example, if I did:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM schema.table1 inner join schema.table2
    WHERE schema.table1.ID1 = schema.table2.ID1
    schema.table1.ID2 = schema.table2.ID2;
```

If I call `UPDATE` on the rows that I get from this query, would the actual values in table1/table2 be changed or is this union just created in dynamic memory and I would just be changing values that get deleted when the query is over?

Comment: A select statement is for retrieving data only. You need a proper programming language and components within that programming language to create an updateable rowset

Comment: @Shadow I'm using select to show the rows I intend to change. If I instead used: `UPDATE table1 SET data = whatever` would that not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update as follows:

```
UPDATE table1 SET data = whateverupdate
WHERE ID1 IN (SELECT ID1 from schema.table1 
    WHERE schema.table1.ID1 = schema.table2.ID1
    and schema.table1.ID2 = schema.table2.ID2);
```

In your inner select statement, you cannot do a `select *` you'll have to select a particular column. This should work because your inner select finds the row in question and feeds it to your update statement. That being said, your inner select has to return the right row you need, else, the wrong row will be updated. Hope this helps.

Comment: If there are duplicates in ID1, so we have some rows that have ID1 = 10, ID2 = 1, and one row that has ID1 = 10 and ID2 = -1, would this still work?

Comment: Yes, it would only update the table you specify in your `Update` statement. In this example, `table1`

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks.